# Will performance be affected when shrinking partitions on 2 RAID HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have a notebook with 2 hard drives (each 500GB) with controller RAID 0 in striping mode.

I have Windows 7 64-bit installed.

Now I can see just one partition (C about 1TB).

My question is: if I create partitions (C and D more or less same size), shrinking from computer management/disk management, will the performance be affected?

Comment: This question doesn't really belong here, and you will surely get a better answer at superuser.com!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes.

The slightly longer and more complex answer is that you will essentially be splitting your drives in two.  This will (probably) result in more read/write head traversal when reading from one partition to the other.  While it is not likely that you would see a huge slowdown, you would be using more power, which is probably already at a premium when you have your laptop unplugged.

I also wonder what your rationale is for doing this?

Comment: How much of a performance hit would it be realistically? I'm interested to know. Personally I'd break the RAID set and format the drives individually, but in terms of his question, do you think you could provide numbers or percentages? I understand the theory of why it would be slower, but I'm interested in values. Would it simply be the loss of the RAID 0 speed improvement, or something more substantial?

Comment: I doubt the actual performance hit would be noticeable except in disk-intensive operations.  The bigger performance hit comes from the power drain (it is a laptop, so this has to be a consideration).  Also, there will be more wear and tear on the drives with the increased read/write head traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do it just to have SO and program on C and myWorks on D but I can managed the situation using folder structure.